# Ruby - defining self method in metaclass of a ruby class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, metaclass, class-method

```
class A
  @@class_var = "A class variable"
  def initialize
    @var = "A instance variable"
  end
  def m1
    puts @var
  end
  def m2
    puts @@class_var
  end
end

class << A
  def self.m3
    puts "im m3"
  end
end
```

What happen to method m3 and how to access the m3 method and where it will be defined in class or metaclass? However if i try to access it using A.m3 or Object class method it does not exist!!

Comment: Short answer is delete `self`.

Comment: It's a bit like asking _"I wrote this code but I have no idea what it does, do you?"_ :-) What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

Every object in Ruby has a hidden *singleton class* sitting between itself and its parent class.

```
class A; end
a = A.new
a.is_a? a.singleton_class                  # true
a.singleton_class.superclass == A          # true
# similarly
A.is_a? A.singleton_class                  # true
A.singleton_class.ancestors.include? Class # true
```

the singleton class is useful because it lets you define methods and such that only apply to a single object.

You can open up an object's singleton class to make changes to it with the `class <<` notation.

```
class << a
  def foobar
  end
end
a.foobar
```

But there's also a shorthand for defining methods in the singleton class:

```
def a.foobar
  # same effect as above
end
a.foobar
```

You combined both notations, so you ended up defining a method in A's singleton class's singleton class. When you define a method in `a`'s singleton class, you can call it on `a`, so your method can be called on A's singleton class.

```
class << A
  # you opened the singleton class, so self is A.singleton_class
  def self.m3
    puts "im m3"
  end
end
A.singleton_class.m3
# in m3
```

Comment: this question has nothing to do with metaprogramming